# Displaying a value of cell that is filtered

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a small problem. I cant find a way how to create a formula that would show a cell value on another page in a excel document.

I have in (both values on both pages) cell one a text name and in cell two a number value.

What would a formula look like if I want to show the value in the first page (value from second page cell two), when a column is text filtered to G9414B = the value of  G9414B would be displayed in a cell?

Please Help if you know how. I cant get it to work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: INDIRECT might be useful, see http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx

Comment: INDIRECT doesnt seem to be the right one. Sorry I didnt ask correctly. I would like to use columns. First sheet I have a column and when filtered to one of the many text inputs it should automaticly search in the second sheet in only one column where these text inputs are written and the value matching the filter in the first sheet is in a cell right to it should be output. Any ideas?

Comment: Still not clear what you are trying to achieve... Try VLOOKUP?

Comment: Nope VLOOKUP only finds the one defined. I need it to find it automatically. I have a column in sheet 1 with x-entries but a lot of them are the same. So I would like to apply a filter to this column to find all entries with same text. When the filter is applied I want it to show me the value of these entries which is on the second sheet. So on the first sheet I have a formula I have a formula that counts the filtered values together and I need one formula that would point out the max value of these filtered values (from sheet2 where the max value is written). Sadly I can't post pics. sry

Comment: @zx8754 can I send you the pics (via mail)? I cant seem to make it work.

Comment: Put your images on http://postimage.org/ and add the link to your post.

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/47vt4g41j/1stpic.jpg and http://s18.postimg.org/f7qfhnf89/2ndpic.jpg

Comment: I hope it helps. So when data is filtered on 1st picture (yellow) to lets say G20A, the formula must look through the whole B column on sheet2 to find the matching text (that is G20A) and write the number from sheet2 (blue : 600) to the first sheet where the formula is written. PLS help:)

Comment: Why not just use VLOOKUP on column B to get MAX value from second sheet?

Comment: That would work if the maximum was in question. I have to check for every one of them: if I filter for G20A the value from sheet2 must be shown as under the same name as the one filtered. And if i filter for G20B the number from G20B must be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

> Why not just use VLOOKUP on column B to get MAX value from second sheet

Add `VLOOKUP` on column B to get maximum value from other sheet, in this picture it is a table with green heading:

[image]

Then, when you filter on column A you can see MAX value per filtered group, in this picture it is filtered for `G2`:

[image]

---

**EDIT:** OK there is a way, you need to use `SUBTOTAL` together with `VLOOKUP`:

[image]

Here is how it looks when filtered:

[image]

Comment: I get where u r going but I just need the value to be written in one cell and nothing more. just the value in your E1.

Comment: See EDIT, you need to use VLOOKUP and SUBTOTAL together.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Indeed did it help. nice one!:)